# Using Service worker how do we chain subsequent requests for a fetch call followed after an update data call?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

Is there any way we can chain request for sync and next  subsequent fetch request where we call an update and subsequent fetch call? Currently I am seeing the fetch call 'jsonGetMyData' is getting called and give me back old data, but if I pause this call in debugger for a sec, it give me updated data. So it seems service worker update is not happening before fetch call, if that's the case how can we control it so that service worker update will happen first then only fetch will be called?

Please advise.

Below is calling part.

```
   if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'SyncManager' in window) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
        .then(function(sw) {
        writeData('myStore', dataObject)
        .then(function() {
            return sw.sync.register('case0-sync');
        })
        .then(function(){
            debugger;
            this.jsonGetMyData(this.get("dataId"));
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }); 
    });
}
```

Below is sample service worker code .

```
 self.addEventListener("sync", function(event) {
    console.log("Background Syncing started...");

  if(event.tag === 'case0-sync'){
     //my update post call goes here

  }else if(event.tag === 'case1-sync'){
   
  }else if(event.tag === 'case2-sync'){
    
  }else if(event.tag === 'case3-sync'){
   
  }else if(event.tag === 'case4-sync'){
    
  }
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  if (event.request.url.indexOf('jsonGetMyData') > -1
   event.respondWith(
               fetch(event.request).then(function(resp){
                return resp;
               }).catch(function(err){
        })
        );
  }
});
```

Comment: at the end of the serviceworker upd is the place to raise a new event "Done" .. this new event can be listened to ... onDone is where you can bind your code for the post-update syncs/fetches

Comment: my understanding is after  it registers 'case0-sync', the control will go to the then block for fetch call...but in bw we have an update call within case0-block which does actual data update and it won't be called instantaneosly when we the register call fires and bw this delay our fetch call fetch and give us old data....is this true?

Comment: review your cache-first vs always-refresh policies in the SW

Comment: ok can you give me a sample/structure of that code how it looks like.

Comment: on cachetypes ( various policies )  from workbox docs : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-strategies  .. more on Service worker in general and lifecycle : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-strategies  review of these links should help u solve your problem.. Network first policy type will make sure your not fetching from a stale cache.

Comment: No, not about the strategy i am asking...my problem is as soon as event tag for update is registered I am firing a fetch call to get the updated data from server. Normally event tag registration and subsequent update call to server happens in almost same time, but some times there is a delay is observed from tag registration to the update call to the server. So while this time on successful registration of tag and in the 'then' block am firing a fetch call to get the latest update, and in this case it happens before update to server and so it gives me old data.

Comment: what should I do to make sure my fetch call for the updated data happens after update to the server? Do I need add some delay in the then block after update tag registration? Since sync block and fetch block are separate in service worker, I don't have control over it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/progressive-web-apps  : "update on reload"  in dev/tests WILL allow you to FORCE updates (SW) onPageLoad.... out in the real world , IMO the SW lifecycle will NOT give you that amount of control on the exact timing of the update that refreshes the page. Optimization of net bandwidth etc can affect the exact time of the SW refresh.. For example, it may be limited to 1 refresh cycle per day on a phone ... you should review docs on "SW lifecycle " for more detail

Comment: okay will do, do you have any recommendation for the logic above for the code snippets?